# Web API controller parameter is null only on GET request

Tags: rest, http, asp.net-web-api, get

So I have a very simple controller that accepts a `Search` object

```
public class ProfileController : ApiController
{
    [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public async Task<ProfileDTO> GetProfile(Search profile)
    {
         //My code
    }
}
```

The `Search` object only contains very simple, primitive data types

```
public class Search
{
    public string Uuid { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Censored { get; set; }
}
```

For testing purposes I am using Swagger to call my API with sample data. For some reason if I make the same call to `api/profile` with the same data the `profile` argument will only contain data during the `POST` call. On a `GET` it is always null.

I only added the `AcceptVerbs("POST")` to demonstrate this issue, but by RESTful design I want the endpoint to only accept `GET` verbs

As of right now I'm just sending some boilerplate sample data such as

```
{
  "Uuid": "string",
  "Email": "string",
  "Name": "string",
  "Censored": true
}
```

I know this is probably a very simple issue, but why is the parameter always null only on a `GET` request?

Comment: You can't send a POST-body in a GET request.

Comment: I'm not sending it manually. Swagger automatically creates the request sample. Using CURL it would look like `curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{
  \"Uuid\": \"string\",
  \"Email\": \"string\",
  \"Name\": \"string\",
  \"Censored\": true
}" "http://localhost:48683/api/Profile"` I've tried doing it manually as well. As I mentioned the POST works fine using just x-www-form-urlencoded, but the GET url params still result in null

Comment: And by manually I mean sending a GET to `localhost:48683/api/profile?Name=test&Uuid=test&Email=test&Censored=true`

Comment: For GET parameter I think your arguments of the function must be: (string uuid, string email, string name, boolean censored)

Comment: Its `application/json` format, so those are just key value pairs.

Comment: In a GET request you have GET parameters and no application/json

Comment: Can't it serialize it into an object?